# Layout issues with fixed position

Tags: html, css

I would like my content to be the only thing that is affected by scrolling. The other elements should stay in place. The content should not go behind the headers or other tools.

What I tried so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/1L9Lnqho/

```
<header> <!-- This is a fixed header with transparency -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#">Messages</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>

<section class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-pills-stacked-example fix-me"> 
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Yes</a></li> 
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">This</a></li> 
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Is</a></li> 
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Silly</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="toolbar fix-me"> 
            <span>TOOL 1</span>
            <span>TOOL 2</span>
            <span>TOOL 3</span>
        </div>
        <div> 
        <b>
            I want this to scroll but the other buttons and 
            layout should stay in place.
            And the scrollbar should stay on the body.
        </b>
        A lot of data here...
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 90px;
}

section {
    padding: 15px;
    border: solid  1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.fix-me {
    position: fixed;
}
```

The main problem is that between the header and the sidebar there is a transparent gap which when I scroll gets content in between. I would like the content to be hidden here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1L9Lnqho/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could add overflow-y:none on body and overflow-y:scroll on section to make the content scroll on the section only

Comment: Could you demonstrate that in my fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1L9Lnqho/19/, is this what you want?: I edited your css like this:     body,html{overflow: hidden; height: 100%; }
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
}

section {
    padding: 15px;
    border: solid  1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 100px;
   overflow:scroll;
   height:100%;
}

.fix-me {
    position: fixed;
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use z-index property with positive values..

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want,

you don't even need position fixed for those elements, or a best approach in case you want it anyway would be ( on my opinion ) to extract the ul and the toolbar from the section.container, or make the nav, toolbar and text-content all siblings inside the section.container.

### HTML

```
<header>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a href="#">Messages</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>

<section class="container section-container">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-pills-stacked-example"> 
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Yes</a></li> 
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">This</a></li> 
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Is</a></li> 
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Silly</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="toolbar"> 
            <span>TOOL 1</span>
            <span>TOOL 2</span>
            <span>TOOL 3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-content"> 
          <!-- LOREM IPSUM HERE -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
}

section {
    padding: 15px;
    border: solid  1px rgba(155,155,155,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}



.section-container {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 4em;
}

.text-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-top: 1em;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

PD: Borders only for testing purposes